# Development time for custom text editor for content generating site in PHP

Tags: php, drupal, text, editing

This is for a web development project.  I an working with one other developer.  We need to be efficient with our time.

We are looking into our options for the text editor in our site.  For beta we are using wizywig editor.  We fear the look and feel does not match the quality of our site.

We are looking for options for our strategy to develop an editor within Drupal CMS using PHP

1. Options to change basic formatting
   a) bold
   b) italic 
   c) font size
   d) underline
2. Real time saving (similar to Google Docs)

What are development options going forward? Should we work from a scratch development or work from a framework?  What are the development time Considerations?

Comment: Hard to say and give guidance here. Best option would be using an editor that fits. Take something existing you can tailor for your needs. But your question is not practically answerable I fear and therefore not fitting for this website here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to weigh your team's experience with both PHP, (AJAX?) and Drupal to estimate the development time.  There's really only 3 options here.  You could develop from scratch, you could take an existing system and rewrite it to fit your needs, or you can search for an existing extension to use with Drupal.  Without judging your teams skills, it would probably be quickest to find the closest collaborative editor to your desires (that also has the appropriate license) and start fitting it to Drupal.  Then modify the rest to meet your specs.  However, that's just an opinion.  Good luck on your quest!